# NiFi DistributedMapCacheServer and flowfiles on different nodes

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I am using NiFi DistributedMapCacheServer to keep track of processed files in my flow. The issue is that we are working in a cluster and to leverage it we are using load balancing in queues so Flowfiles are not on the same node. Once they are arriving to Put/GetDistributedMapCache that is using DistributedMapCacheClient with fixed name of one of the hosts it only works when arriving Flowfile is on the same node as the one specified in DistributedMapCacheClient- for others we are getting:
 `FetchDistributedMapCache[id=d4713096-5ae5-1cb4-b777-202948e39e50] Unable to communicate with cache when processing StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=5b1e8092-5bc5-4213-97a3-fa023691973f,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1587393798960-14, container=default, section=14], offset=983015, length=5996],offset=0,name=bf15d684-4100-4aa5-9fb5-fa0ddb21b140,size=5996] due to No route to host: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`

Is there any way to set up DMC server/client to work in such case, or can I somehow route all flowfiles to explicitly given node?

Answer (score 1):

This means the hostname/ip-address that you specified in the DistributedMapCacheClient for the location of the server is unreachable by the other nodes in your cluster. Your nodes must be able to communicate since you have a cluster, so you just need to set this to the correct value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I get hostname and ip good (I tried both) lets say it is pp2xodr01nfi002.xxx.xxx.xxx. I thought that problem might be some firewall rule but the port 4557 is open:
` sudo lsof -i -P -n
java      24073        nifi 2865u  IPv4 2479691      0t0  TCP *:4557 (LISTEN) `

Comment: Yep- must be something with network config. If I change to port 4558 that is in theory blocked I have the same behavior- only flowfile from specified node is processed others throws errors.